# ARM Assembly Printing Large and Incorrect value

Tags: assembly, arm

Here is what I believe to be the most relevant code, there are other values stored down to [fp, #-24]. Ive tried hard-coding the values to [fp, #-8] and [fp, #-12]. Im unsure as to if some sort of stack mismanagement is occurring or if im just missing some important component of the printf function.

```
.data

var: .word

prompt1: .asciz "Largest number:\n"
prompt2: .asciz "Smallest number:\n"
input: .asciz "%d"
test: .asciz "%d and %d\n"

.align 2
.text
.align 2

.global main

.func main
main:
    push {fp, lr}
    add fp, sp, #4


    sub sp, sp, #20

    ldr r0, =prompt1
    bl printf

   @  var1
    ldr r0, =input
    sub r1, fp, #8
    bl scanf

    ldr r0, =prompt2
    bl printf

    @ var2
    ldr r0, =input
    sub r1, fp, #12
    bl scanf

    ldr r0, =test
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    str r2, [fp, #-12]
    bl printf

sub sp, fp, #4
pop {fp, pc}
.endfunc
```

returns

```
 [large number] and 0
```

EDIT: Potentially useful info from GDB

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x10438: file gcd.s, line 19.
Starting program: /home/pi/gcd 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at gcd.s:19
19      push {fp, lr}
(gdb) step
21      add fp, sp, #4
(gdb) step
24      sub sp, sp, #20
(gdb) step
26      ldr r0, =prompt1
(gdb) step
27      bl printf
(gdb) step
__printf (format=0x21048 "Largest number:\n") at printf.c:33
33  printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) step
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0xb6fb7d90 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, 
    format=0x21048 "Largest number:\n", format@entry=0x0, ap=..., ap@entry=...)
    at vfprintf.c:1278
1278    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) step
1282    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) step
1293    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) step
1315    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) step
__find_specmb (format=<optimized out>) at vfprintf.c:1304
1304    in vfprintf.c
(gdb) step
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0xb6fb7d90 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, 
    format=0x21048 "Largest number:\n", format@entry=0x0, ap=..., ap@entry=...)
    at vfprintf.c:1315
1315    in vfprintf.c
```

[full pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BnZiRuD0)

Comment: what are you trying to do here and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Probably you want `ldr` not `str` before `printf`.  `r1` and `r2` still hold whatever garbage scanf left in them.  (And you just overwrote your inputs with that garbage, too :P)  **Use a debugger to single-step your code and examine register values.**

Comment: @old_timer I would like the code to return `[input val] and [input val]`. Also I made a mistake in my post, it actually prints `[large number] and 0`

Comment: @PeterCordes Ive added some relevant debugging info to the post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your bug is what I commented before: use `ldr r1, [fp, #-8]` instead of `str r1, [fp, #-8]` (and same for r2) to reload the scanf conversion results from the address where it stored them.  That was just a brain-fart right?  Or do you need a detailed explanation of why you need to from the stack instead of storing to it there?  And BTW, use `ni` to step *over* printing the prompt, or set a breakpoint right before the final printf that prints the values.

Comment: @PeterCordes I live in a perpetual brain fart haha. Unfortunately changing that error didn't fix the issue. Im new to this so sorry for the confusing debug info, where do I put `ni`? In the source file before the statement?

Comment: @user8585207: `ni` is a GDB command, short for `nexti`.  Use GDB's built-in help.  And BTW, your GDB output isn't confusing (to me), just useless :/  What you want is to step over calls until you get to right before the final printf, then print register contents.  (e.g. info reg, or `print $r1` ; `print $r2`, or use `layout reg`)

Comment: @PeterCordes Got it. Here is an updated log https://pastebin.com/tEbn2GWH. Is this of any help? `[Inferior 1 (process 7201) exited with code 050]` is interesting. Also, here is a link to the full source file.https://pastebin.com/V2Uk9mNg You can see my test bit before `compare:`, Im hoping once that is outputting the correct values the rest will work well

Comment: Did you notice my edit to the previous comment about printing registers?  The whole point of single-stepping is to examine the machine state at the point right before the call.  Update your question with that.